# Initialize base subobject with dependent type name in derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Given this sample code with class `C` deriving from `A` or `B` depending on policy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    A(int a) { std::cout << a << "\n"; }
};

struct B
{
    B(int a) { std::cout << -a << "\n"; }
};

template<bool>
struct policy;

template<>
struct policy<true> { typedef A type; };

template<>
struct policy<false> { typedef B type; };

template<typename T>
struct C : public policy<std::is_polymorphic<T>::value>::type
{
    C() : /* ????? */(5) {}
};

int main()
{
    C<int> a; // should print -5
    C<std::ostream> b; // should print 5
}
```

How do I initialize the base class of `C`? (or, if it's not possible, is there a workaround?)

Comment: Won't `C() : type(5) {}` work here?

Comment: @NeilKirk typedefs aren't inherited, are they?

Comment: @Oguk They are normally http://ideone.com/Vj4ovx But I can't get this Q to compile using a typedef

Comment: Works for me they way I described in my answer: http://ideone.com/DRQT6r

Comment: @NeilKirk I think we were both on the wrong track: typedefs are inherited as you said, but here we are inheriting from "type" (and not from the template class containing the typedef "type"), which is just A or B, so it can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it just the way you found the base class of `C`:

```
template<typename T>
struct C : public policy<std::is_polymorphic<T>::value>::type
{
    C() : policy<std::is_polymorphic<T>::value>::type(5) {}
};
```

Of course, to make it more readable, you can also add a typedef (maybe you will need the base class multiple times within `C`, then it's worth it). This would look like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct C : public policy<std::is_polymorphic<T>::value>::type
{
    typedef typename policy<std::is_polymorphic<T>::value>::type Base;
    C() : Base(5) {}
};
```

To make it a little less ugly, you could also add another layer of indirection, e.g. a template class `BaseForC` that yields the correct base as `BaseForC<T>::type` and encapsulates what `policy` and `is_polymorphic` are doing now into one class.

Comment: I had a real hard time deciding which answer to accept, so I upvoted both yours and KerrekSB's answer. Decided to accept yours because it's more explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lazy solution:

```
template <typename T,
          typename Base = typename std::conditional<
                              std::is_polymorphic<T>::value, A, B>::type>
struct C : Base
{
    C() : Base(5) {}
};
```

The has the cost of giving your template `C` a different signature, and people might abuse that.